# Cookie get expires own

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, session-cookies

I have an e-commerce web site. I use cookies. But some clients, reported me an error about cookies. I create a cookie after user add a product to cart. After click to buy now button, cookie expries in mycart.aspx page. You can see my history in belongs pics.

I add product to cart and everything is ok =>
[image]

As you can see, expire date is ok too.

[image]

After I click buy now button, redirecting to mycart.aspx but it says, cart is empty.

[image]

When I check the cookie expire time I see this view. Cookie got expired.

[image]

Here is my cookie set and get codes:

```
public bool SetCookie(string cookieName, object cookieValue, DateTime expirationDate)
{
    try
    {

        //Eğer atanmak istenen cookie daha önce oluşturuldu ise, içini boşaltıyoruz.
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName] != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Remove(cookieName);
        }

        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        bf.Serialize(ms, cookieValue);
        byte[] bArr = ms.ToArray();

        MemoryStream objStream = new MemoryStream();

        //stream nesnesini sıkıştır
        DeflateStream objZS = new DeflateStream(objStream, CompressionMode.Compress);
        objZS.Write(bArr, 0, bArr.Length);
        objZS.Flush();
        objZS.Close();

        byte[] bytes = objStream.ToArray();
        string sCookieVal = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

        HttpCookie cook = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
        cook.Value = sCookieVal;
        cook.Expires = expirationDate;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cook);

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        throw exc;
    }
}

public object GetCookie(string cookieName)
{
    if (cookieName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("cookieName");
    try
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName] != null)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName].Value != "")
            {
                byte[] bytCook =
                    Convert.FromBase64String(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName].Value);
                MemoryStream inMs = new MemoryStream(bytCook);
                inMs.Seek(0, 0);

                DeflateStream zipStream = new DeflateStream(inMs, CompressionMode.Decompress, true);
                byte[] bArr = ReadFullStream(zipStream);
                zipStream.Flush();
                zipStream.Close();

                MemoryStream outMs = new MemoryStream(bArr);
                outMs.Seek(0, 0);

                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                return bf.Deserialize(outMs, null);
            }
        } return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw (ex);
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea what happen?

Comment: Most probably you are setting wrong expiration dates when you add the cookie. Can you share the sections where you call `SetCookie`?

Comment: @CyberDude, I don't think as you. Here is my set call: BasarCookie.SetCookie("sepet", sepet,DateTime.Now.AddHours(5));

Comment: Cookies don't change on their own. It would have been useful to also show the raw response of your shopping cart page so we could see if the cookie was received there too.